# HAXM Stopped working after I updated Eclipse and JDK 1.7 Mac OS X 10.8.x

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

So I had HAXM working on my system, installed the hotfix and everything and then I updated my SDKs from the SDK manager. After doing this Eclipse told me that I needed to upgrade to JDK 1.7 so I did that. Now my HAXM devices won't work in the emulator (normal emulation works). When I launch I get the status of "HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode" and then "New emulator found: emulator-5554" and then "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched..." But, the emulator pops up and then just stays black. I've tried recreating the AVD and no luck there either.

Comment: I have the same problem except it has happened to me since the beginning of my android development entrepreneurship. I hope we get an answer.

Comment: If you run console logcat, does it display any log messages from the emulator starting up? An error message would help a lot. HAXM seems fragile. Did you try uninstalling it, rebooting, reinstalling it, and maybe rebooting again?